# "sftp: command not found" running sftp from Unix Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, sftp

I can transfer a file from one server to another using `sftp` in the prompt.

I try using `sftp` in a shell script and I get the following error:

```
"sftp: command not found"
```

I tried the below code from a script:

```
sftp ${USER}@${HOST} <<EOF
quote pass ${PASSWD}
cd  ${PATH}
mput *.csv
EOF
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an absolute file location instead of depending on the path - for instance the sftp binary is probably located in `/usr/bin/` so instead of just using `sftp` - try to use `/usr/bin/sftp`

To find out where the binary is located use the which command

`which sftp`

Comment: hey Thanks a lot.. It works.. :) It asks for the password in prompt..How do I avoid this?

Comment: You need to set up public key authentication. [http://superuser.com/questions/15984/how-do-i-automate-sftp-to-get-rid-of-the-password-prompt]http://superuser.com/questions/15984/how-do-i-automate-sftp-to-get-rid-of-the-password-prompt